# Call ID include index into onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have variable for index++

```
var folderIndex = 1;
let currentFolderIndex = folderIndex++;
```

i want to **call table ID** into my onclick .

```
<table id="tableAudience' + currentFolderIndex + '" ></table>
<div onclick="openFolder(event, 'howTocall table ID in here')" ></div>
```

How to do it?

i dont know how to set my id because there will be a conflict of quotes

`onclick="openFolder(event, 'howTocall table ID in here')"`

Image of my Code : http://prntscr.com/h82axw

**I'm not use JSFiddle because I only use js and css files.**

Thx before.

Comment: use `this` context

Comment: `<table id="tableAudience' + currentFolderIndex + '" ></table>` this doesn't look valid

Comment: @JaromandaX may be OP is trying to dynamically add Table

Comment: right ... would be more useful to see something that isn't pseudo code ... unless OP wants a pseudo answer of course :p

Comment: something like $(body).append("<table id="'tableAudience'+current...)

Comment: *"there will be a conflict of quotes"* - Not if you learn about how to escape quotation characters in string literals. Then you could include the ID on that line in a similar way to the line before. Though a better solution would be to use DOM navigation properties/methods rather than IDs.

Comment: @JaromandaX I use it for append.

Comment: You can see my real code http://prntscr.com/h82axw

Comment: i want to call tableAudience ID include index

Comment: @CalvinAnanda just one more question..will the table always & always be above the div...is it a guarantee??

Comment: no, I want the table to appear by id on onclick.
https://prnt.sc/h82fr2

Comment: could you have a look at my answer...i have done a demo.. you can "run code snippet"

Comment: i use append, in the console, if i create first button will be written button1 and table1.

Comment: @CalvinAnanda ..could you explain the button thing with some code please

Comment: [here image](http://prntscr.com/h82hb8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the onCLick Without worrying about the ID

```
   <table id="tableAudience1" > </table>
    <div onclick="openFolder(event,this)"> First Table </div>
```

and on the onclick function you can detect the ID using this

```js
function  openFolder(event,item){
     // will give you the table ID
   console.log( $(item).prev().attr("id"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<table id="tableAudience1" > </table>
<div onclick="openFolder(event,this)"> First Table </div>

<br/>  

<table id="tableAudience2" > </table>
<div onclick="openFolder(event,this)"> Second Table </div>


<br/> 

<table id="tableAudience3" > </table>
<div onclick="openFolder(event,this)"> Third Table </div>

<br/> 

<table id="tableAudience4" > </table>
<div onclick="openFolder(event,this)"> Fourth Table </div>
```

Comment: Despite its name, that's not what `.closest()` does. The elements are siblings.

Comment: `.closest()` bubbles up to parent only **not siblings**

Comment: isnt table a parent to div... ?? see the html in OP

Comment: ohhh just saw...table is not containing div...hence not parent but siblings...let me alter my answer

Comment: I see ending tag of table before starting tag of div